# Multiple ruby installations for multiple projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I want to use ruby 1.8.7 for one project and ruby 1.9.3 for another project.
Is it possible to use both versions simultaneously for both projects with rvm, and have them deployed. Is it possible to do it with .rvmrc? How can I configure .rvmrc specific to project.

Comment: you can do this locally with `rvm`. Or are you talking about the production server?

Comment: For any mode. development mode is ok. But can I use multiple rubies simultaneously? With `rvm` I will have to switch between different versions.  What I want is, each project uses seperate ruby version simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pow](http://pow.cx/) to run more than one ruby simultaneously.

From their front page:

> Tame multiple Rubies. With full support for rbenv and Bundler, Pow
>   makes it simple to run multiple apps at once, each with its own
>   version of Ruby and its own set of gems. Testing your apps on
>   alternative runtimes like Rubinius has never been easier. And gem
>   activation errors are finally a thing of the past.

It will require some setup, but I guess this will get you going ;)

Comment: Why rack-based web server POW help OP install several Ruby version?

Comment: it won't help him install the rubies, but he already has rvm. It will help him run the different rubies he has installed simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should have no problem deploying and running ruby projects of different versions using `rvm`, as long as they are run in different processes - each process will run in its own ruby environment.

You should simply put a [`.rvmrc` file at the base of each project](http://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc#project), each pointing to the relevant ruby version, and then launch the relevant process from the relevant project's root:

> The project .rvmrc file is different than the system & user. System &
>   user rvmrc files are meant for altering the settings and behavior of
>   RVM as a whole. The project rvmrc files are intended to be used to
>   setup your project's ruby environment when you switch to the project
>   root directory.